# Estimating final grades given midterm grades (knowing correlation, average, and sd)

Tags: statistics, regression

The problem states:

> In an Economics class, midterm scores average out to 75 with a standard deviation of 15, so does the
>   scores on the final. The correlation between midterm scores and final scores is 0.5. Use the given
>   information to estimate the average final score for the students whose midterm scores were 80.

I know beta 1 can be estimated by the sample covariance of (X,Y) over the Sample var of X. If I can find beta 0 as well, I have a full estimated linear regression equation and can plug in to get my estimates from there. How would I develop this equation with the information given.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y_i$ be final exam scores and $X_i$ be midterm scores.
The regression line must pass through the point $(\bar X, \bar Y),$
so $\bar Y = \hat \beta_0 + \hat \beta_1 \bar X.$ You say you know
all the values in this equation except for $\hat \beta_0.$ Solve.